# Failed to convert a pine 3 script to version 4

Tags: pine-script

I have this pine3 Trading view script which I converted to pine 4 using the TV converter .

https://codeshare.io/5ZYxpV

however when I execute it after the conversion, I receive this error

```
line 110: Variable 'results' was declared with 'series[integer]' type. Cannot assign it expression of type 'series[float]'.
```

how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For line 104, use this to declare the "float" explicitly:

```
    float results = 0 + bar_index  //tv series spoofing
```

You can then safely ignore the compiler warning on line 78:
[image]